# How to indent select text by four spaces

Tags: jquery

When I select multiple lines of text or code and then click on my code button

It should indent all selected code by **four spaces** but for some reason will only indent the first line

```
    demo
demo
demo
```

Example Only [Codepen](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/dOrmWy)

> **Question:** How can I make sure it indents all selected text not just on
>   the one line

```
$('.c').click(function() {
    wrapText("message", "   ", "");
});
```

Full Script

```
function wrapText(elementID, openTag, closeTag) {
    var textArea = $('#' + elementID);
    var len = textArea.val().length;
    var start = textArea[0].selectionStart;
    var end = textArea[0].selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
    var replacement = openTag + selectedText + closeTag;
    textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + replacement + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
}

$('.b').click(function() {
    wrapText("message", "**", "**");
});

$('.i').click(function() {
    wrapText("message", "*", "*");
});

$('.c').click(function() {
    wrapText("message", "   ", "");
});
```

Comment: that's because you made your code that way. second parameter of writeText method is added at the beginning (the white spaces) and third parameter is added at the end of the selected text. You should make a different function that adds whitespaces in front/after every new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick Check : [**Working JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/8ehafz1h/1/)

> **Question**: How can I make sure it indents all selected text not just on the one line

Currently when you apply any operations on the multi line text you are just adding extra characters to start and end of the selection. But when it comes to `indent` **you need to apply it to beginning of each line**.

So I would recommend you to pass in a new parameter into your function saying if the operation type is `indent`. If so then use regex and replace all the occurrence of `\n` with `\n` + `your indent space`.

The code changes are as below.

```
function wrapText(elementID, openTag, closeTag,operationType) { //new parameter added
    // your current logic 
    var replacement;
    if(operationType === "indent"){
      var multiLineReplace = '\n'+openTag;
      replacement = openTag + selectedText.replace(/\n/g,multiLineReplace) + closeTag; //using regex to replace all instances of `\n` with `\n` + your indent spaces.
    }
    else{
       replacement = openTag + selectedText + closeTag;
    }

    textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + replacement + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
}
```

And your script changes to

```
$('.c').click(function() {
    wrapText("message", "   ", "","indent"); // pass in operationType
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help

Comment: @wolfgang1983 glad I could help.. happy coding!!